# Handling semi-structured data in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

how to handle data in a column titled 'combined' of the format: {"RAG":1233, "BRN":3455, "EDN": 467}. I want to convert this into a new table with 2 different column as:
[new_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IquP.png)

Comment: Are the keys RAG, BRN, EDN fixed or are they dynamic?

Comment: What have you tried? What issue did you face?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Snowflake table function "Flattens" to achieve this goal.

FLATTEN is a table function that takes a VARIANT, OBJECT, or ARRAY column and produces a lateral view (i.e. an inline view that contains correlation referring to other tables that precede it in the FROM clause).

e.g.

```
SELECT 
KEY,VALUE
FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON('{
    "RAG":1233,
    "BRN":3455,
    "EDN": 467
}')));
```